# Strpos find brand names

Tags: php

```
$pos = strpos($arr_row1['name'], $arr_row['value']." ");
if ($pos !== false){
```

The following code helps me match product title to a brand
So I have an array of brands `"GoPro", "HP"` etc... also some unusual brands such as `"Dy" "GE".` The problem with this code that it will match `"Ready"` to brand `"Dy`" and if I chacne it to match `" " . brand . " "` it will not match brands by title if it stars like `"HP Laptop"` any ideas how to avoid the issues and still match the right brand by title?

Comment: `strpos` returns `int` and you compare `pos` to `false` with type

Comment: @bartek that correct ;) you should read the documentation. If strpos does't find anything it returns false. So if you check it with !== its correct.

Comment: `strpos` is case-sensitive, and will not find "Dy" within "Ready". And as a non-technical point, "HP Laptop" isn't a brand. "HP" is a brand that makes laptops.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes you're correct it's case-sensitive I thought it's not anyway the brand is "dy" so it did match "Ready" i know "HP Laptop" isn't a brand it's just an example "HP Pavilion blabla..." and if it see HP it will assign it as a brand HP not as HP laptops

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
$pos = preg_match('/\b('.$arr_row1['name'].')\b/', $arr_row['value']);
if ($pos == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change condition with this:

```
if(preg_match('/\s?' . preg_quote($arr_row1['name'], '/') .  '\s.*/', $arr_row['value'] . ' '))
```

Comment: thank you, can you explain this a little bit? Is this case sensitive? Is there no way to keep using strpos match it by same length like "dy" 2 digits for example will solve the problem?